# Git multiple commits: Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm trying to commit some files in separate commits in a Jenkins Pipeline using the following code:

```
            sh '''
                git add $SOURCE_ENV/metadetail/current/*
                git commit -m "Updating Snapshot Metadata"
                git add $SOURCE_ENV/release/*
                git commit -m "Package for Release Branch"
                git push -u origin HEAD:$BRANCH_NAME
                git checkout master
                git checkout -b $BRANCH_NAMEfb
                git cherry-pick $BRANCH_NAME
                git push -u origin HEAD:$BRANCH_NAMEfb
            '''
```

The aim here is to do 2 separate commits on the current branch, create a new feature branch from master, then cherry-pick the 2nd commit from original branch onto the new branch.
This is failing the jenkins build following the first commit, with the following message:

```
+ git commit -m Updating Snapshot Metadata
HEAD detached from 4b8ea1e
Untracked files:
    dPATCH/release/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present
script returned exit code 1
```

I'm not certain what is going on - my understanding is that only files in 'staging' are important when committing so not sure why the other files are being picked up when I'm only initially running git add on a subset of the files. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not certain what is going on

As I mentioned in "[Adding git branch as a properties using Gradle on Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46263032/6309)", Jenkins would, by default, checkout the HEAD, not the branch, setting its workspace in a detached HEAD mode (hence your first commit output)

You need to make sure to checkout the branch, before starting making commits.

See [Jenkins issue 6856: Git builds with detached head no matter what](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-6856?focusedCommentId=299919&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-299919):

> The "pipeline syntax" link on the left of most pipeline job pages will open a page where you can prototype the code you need to perform a checkout to a specific branch.
>   Use the "checkout" selection from that list (not the "git" selection), then select "Git" and add the "Additional Behaviours" for "Check out to specific local branch".
>   You can then set a specific branch name, or you can use "**" to indicate that it should use the branch name from the repository where the clone was performed.

Comment: Thanks very much, sorted the issue with your suggestion :D